# xamarin android black splash screen issue

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mobile, splash-screen

So i'm currently trying to display a splash screen on my app. I don't have an error on my code, but when i'm building my app, the log shows me this:

> 10-31 15:19:47.541 I/mono-stdout( 1118): Start loader splash screen
>   10-31 15:19:47.676 I/dalvikvm-heap( 1118): Grow heap (frag case) to 21.377MB for 11520016-byte allocation
>   10-31 15:19:47.801 W/dalvikvm( 1118): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/graphics/drawable/Icon;)
>   10-31 15:19:47.801 I/dalvikvm( 1118): Could not find method android.widget.ImageView.setImageIcon, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageIcon
>   10-31 15:19:47.801 W/dalvikvm( 1118): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 23537: Landroid/widget/ImageView;.setImageIcon (Landroid/graphics/drawable/Icon;)V
>   10-31 15:19:47.801 D/dalvikvm( 1118): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
>   10-31 15:19:47.801 I/dalvikvm( 1118): Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
>   10-31 15:19:47.801 W/dalvikvm( 1118): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 702: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
>   10-31 15:19:47.801 D/dalvikvm( 1118): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
>   10-31 15:19:47.801 I/dalvikvm( 1118): Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
>   10-31 15:19:47.801 W/dalvikvm( 1118): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 704: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
>   10-31 15:19:47.801 D/dalvikvm( 1118): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
>   10-31 15:19:47.966 I/dalvikvm-heap( 1118): Grow heap (frag case) to 37.397MB for 16777232-byte allocation
>   10-31 15:19:47.986 D/dalvikvm( 1118): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1026K, 7% free 35974K/38300K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 19ms
>   10-31 15:19:48.151 E/dalvikvm( 1118): Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
>   10-31 15:19:48.151 W/dalvikvm( 1118): VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 240 (Landroid/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable;) in Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageHelper;
>   fin doit loader splash screen
>   10-31 15:19:48.151 D/dalvikvm( 1118): VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x000c
>   10-31 15:19:48.151 I/mono-stdout( 1118): End loader splash screen

A grey screen appears, instead of the splash, screen for 4-5 seconds, then my app main screen is displayed.

First i grow the Java max heap size (1G or 2G), but it does not fix.

I thought the issue cames from the size of my images, but when i change them for low-res images, the issue is still the same.

Here is the xml code of my splash screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/SplashScreenBackground">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/IconSplashScreen"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is the code of my splash screen activity:

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        Console.WriteLine("start loader splash screen");

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SplashScreen);

        Console.WriteLine("end doit loader splash screen");

        Thread.Sleep(1500);

        Console.WriteLine("Pause de 1.5 sec terminé");

        StartActivity(typeof(TargetActivity));
        OverridePendingTransition(Resource.Animation.abc_fade_in, Resource.Animation.abc_fade_out);

    }
```

I use the material design library.

How can i fix that?

Comment: Could you please show your drawable for splash screen and your activity for this splash screen so we can try to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Hi, i edit my post by adding my xml and activity code.

Comment: Thread.Sleep(1500) isn't the best approach. It will cause your main GUI Thread to halt completely. This can result in android "thinking" your app has crashed and then completely tearing down everything.

I would recommend using tasks for handling the delay.

`
    Task startup = new Task(() => Task.Delay(1500));
    startup.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            StartActivity(intent);
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    startup.Start();
`